# How to upload binary files to s3 using node js using s3 key attribute

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I need to download and extracted **tar.gz** files from **s3 bucket** and upload to another bucket.The files are downloaded properly and the **result** is returning as **binary data** using **s3.getObject**.

I need to pass the **binary data (files)** to **s3** bucket to upload using **s3.putOBject**.

But  I dont know what "**name**" has to give for **"Key"** params in **s3.putOBject** when we push the **binary files to s3.putObject**. Kindly help me.

**This is my code**

```
var bucketName = "my.new.Bucket-Latest";

var fileKey = "Employee.tar.gz";

var params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileKey };

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data,callback) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
} 
else {
    zlib.gunzip(data.Body, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var extractedData = result;
            s3.putObject({
            Bucket: "bucketName",
            Key: " ",
            Body: extractedData,
            ContentType: 'content-type'
            }, function (err) {
                 console.log('uploaded file: ' + err);
            });
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well even your own code says, that key is filename. Just generate some filename and assign to key property. It is like filesystem. When you creating a new file, you should give some name to it.

Comment: I can give the name for single file.But am uploading multiple files as binary,In this scenario wat name I can give?Pls suggest me

Comment: How about ManyFilesArchived.gz? I told you same thing as with file system, bucket are just "folders".

Comment: should I iterate  as each files from binary and assign to key? kindly help me how to proceed in detail?